# Holding Multiple Schengen Visas

Tags: visa, schengen, europe

**Situation:**

- I am Indian national working and living in UK. I have two trips planned to the Schengen zone:

  - **April 11th - 15th, 2024:** This trip falls within the validity period of my existing Schengen visa (expiring May 5th, 2024).
  - **June 10th - 19th, 2024:** This trip falls outside the validity period of my current visa.
- I have applied for a new Schengen visa with an appointment in March and expect it to be issued by the end of the month.

**Questions:**

- Does holding a new visa application or receiving a new visa impact the validity of my existing visa?
- Can I use both visas separately for my different trips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second visa, when issued, would probably start when the first ends.

There will be no overlapping.

**Note**: This would **not** affect any planned trip that can take place during the switchover (2024-05-05/06)

- you would enter on the first
- and exit on the second

Comment: Isn't there an article of the visa code that specifies this procedure explicitly?

Comment: If there is, I can't find it.  But after finding the relevant part of the visa handbook, I suspect that this is what I was recalling.  The version of the document I have is from January 28, 2020, and the relevant section is part II, section 1.3: "If an applicant holds a valid visa but which does not cover the next intended stay entirely, the currently valid visa should not be revoked, but the period of validity of the next visa should start on the day following the expiry of the currently valid one.  ..."